# Load-testing django application using Jmeter

Tags: django, jmeter, load-testing

I am a newbie in web-development and am trying to use Jmeter for doing load testing on our site. I have some very basic and stupid doubts regarding Jmeter and how to analyze its results.

I want to analyze the following parameters of our site.

1. Response time under load - The average duration of a Web surfing Session.
2. Capacity - Total number of successful urls calls per second measured over all users.
3. Stability - The percentage of failed web surf sessions ,measured over all users.

I have checked all the listeners of Jmeter, they do not give all these graphs.
How do i get them?
Will i have to write scripts for them?
Are these parameters sufficient to describe at least the basic functionality of load testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **1** and **2** you can get from the [JMeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) project, the **3** - from jmeter's default Summary Report:

1. Response Times Over Time
   http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime
2. Response Codes per Second
   http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond
3. Summary Report, "Error %" column
   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report

Comment: All graphs use approximiation and average values. Much more precise results could be obtained by analysis of "raw" datas that was recorded to .csv files from listeners.